# In fancybox, show only photos from specific div in lightbox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-3

I have 2 points in my page, where there are some pictures using `fancybox`. When the user clicks in a photo, then the user sees the image in `lightbox`, while the other images are show as thumb in right side.

[image]

What I try to do, is that the user in the above view could only see only the photos of the div that clicked and not all of them! So if he clicks, the 1st image of the first `div`, then he should see only the 2 images in the thumbview...

I tried to user `data-fancybox="images1"` and `data-fancybox="images2"` in the anchors of each div, but it didn't worked..

```js
$('[data-fancybox="images"]').fancybox({
  buttons: [
    'slideShow',
    'zoom',
    'fullScreen',
    'download',
    'thumbs',
    'close'
  ],
  thumbs: {
    autoStart: true
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>


<div class="row mb-5">
<a href="https://source.unsplash.com/IvfoDk30JnI/1500x1000" data-fancybox="images" data-caption="caprtion..">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/IvfoDk30JnI/240x160" />
</a>

<a href="https://source.unsplash.com/0JYgd2QuMfw/1500x1000" data-fancybox="images" data-caption="caprtion..">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/0JYgd2QuMfw/240x160" />
</a>
</div>


<div class="row">
<a href="https://source.unsplash.com/xAgvgQpYsf4/1500x1000" data-fancybox="images" data-caption="caprtion..">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/xAgvgQpYsf4/240x160" />
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using same values for `data-fancybox` attribute (for example, `data-fancybox="images1"`) would tell the script to group them, demo:

```js
$('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
  buttons: [
    'slideShow',
    'zoom',
    'fullScreen',
    'download',
    'thumbs',
    'close'
  ],
  thumbs: {
    autoStart: true
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>


<div class="row mb-5">
<a href="https://source.unsplash.com/IvfoDk30JnI/1500x1000" data-fancybox="images1" data-caption="caprtion..">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/IvfoDk30JnI/240x160" />
</a>

<a href="https://source.unsplash.com/0JYgd2QuMfw/1500x1000" data-fancybox="images1" data-caption="caprtion..">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/0JYgd2QuMfw/240x160" />
</a>
</div>


<div class="row">
<a href="https://source.unsplash.com/xAgvgQpYsf4/1500x1000" data-fancybox="images2" data-caption="caprtion..">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/xAgvgQpYsf4/240x160" />
</a>
</div>
```

But, to apply your customization, make sure that your selector actually returns your elements. For example, if you have `$('[data-fancybox="images"]').fancybox({..});`, it would not select elements having `data-fancybox="images1"`